# PowerShell - MultiLine Command Tried The Suggestions not working- How to continue to next line

Tags: powershell

New to Powershell is completing some examples.
From what I read in the book and on this site a ` or ^ should work if I wanted to continue a powershell command to the next line.

Command I am trying to get on two lines:
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $(Get-Content -Path C:\Users\obrientim\Downloads\pjpconfig) -DifferenceObject $(Get-Content -Path C:\Users\obrientim\Downloads\pjpconfig2)

I have tried both ` and ^ in various locations but each time I hit enter to go to new line I receive an error. Does it matter where I try to continue to new line I believe the ` should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't use `^`.  The line continuation character is ` (backtick) e.g.:

```
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject  $(Get-Content C:\pjpconfig) `
               -DifferenceObject $(Get-Content C:\pjpconfig2)
```

Note: there can be no spaces or tabs after the backtick.

You can also use `|` and `{` to indicate a command is multiline e.g.:

```
Get-Process | 
    Where id -eq $pid
```

or

```
Get-Process | Foreach {
    "The process name is $($_.Name)"
}
```

Comment: I have tried your suggestion but receive a error Incomplete string token using the backtick, An empty pipe element is not allowed using | and missing closing } in statement block using {

Comment: All of the examples above work.  Try starting a powershell session with the -noprofile option `powershell.exe -noprofile` and try the backtick again.

Comment: I tried powershell -noprofile and script running, waited 30 minutes and was still running to killed it.

Comment: I should have mentioned I was using Powershell ISE your command worked fine when I switched to regular powershell console. I didn't think it would matter which console I used?

Comment: I don't get it, I have tried the -noprofile option when I use powershell ISE but I can't use multiple lines . What is different between ISE and regular shell in that the backtick will not work

Comment: +1, but I'm still going to be picky. The backtick is not the continuation character, but the escape character. When used to continue a line, what you're doing is escaping the line end, which in turn is why there can't be anything between the backtick and the line end.

Comment: Yup, the docs say that backtick is the escape character which can be used to `to indicate line continuation`.  But most folks are just going to think of it as the line continuation char instead of line continuation being just a happy side-effect of escaping a character (newline). :-)